# Ошибка при создании объекта

Tags: c#

При создании Table Unit выдаёт [image: результат работы UnitTest]
Предполагаемый лог UnitTest https://yadi.sk/d/KnbKKhyEYZq6Hw
При этом, если в методе `CreateRows` будет отсутствовать строка `r[i] = new Row(this, i, columns, height);`, то всё пройдет успешно. Какие могут быть проблемы у этого кода?

```
namespace TableNet
{
    public class Table
    {

        private readonly Cell[,] _cells;

        public Cell this[int i, int j]
        {
            get => _cells[i, j];
            set
            {
                if(value != null)
                    _cells[i, j] = value;
                else throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
        }

        public ReadOnlyCollection<Row> Rows { get; }
        public ReadOnlyCollection<Column> Columns { get; }


        public Table(int rows, int columns)
        {
            _cells = new Cell[rows, columns];

            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    _cells[i, j] = new Cell();
                }
            }
            Rows = CreateRows(rows, columns, Row.DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT);
            Columns = CreateColumns(rows, columns, Column.DEFAULT_COLUMN_WIDTH);
        }

        public ReadOnlyCollection<Row> CreateRows(int rows, int columns, int height)
        {
            Row[] r = new Row[rows];
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                r[i] = new Row(this, i, columns, height);
            }
            return Array.AsReadOnly(r);
        }

        private ReadOnlyCollection<Column> CreateColumns(int rows, int columns, int width)
        {
            Column[] r = new Column[columns];
            for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            {
                r[i] = new Column(this, i, rows, width);
            }
            return Array.AsReadOnly(r);
        }
    }
}
```

### код Row. Column такой же

```
namespace TableNet
{
    public class Row
    {
        public const int DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT = 3;


        public int Height 
        {
            get => Height; 
            set => Height = Math.Max(0, value);
        }

        public int Columns { get; }

        private readonly Table _table;

        private readonly int _rowIndex;

        //public char Filler { set => Cells.ForEach(c => c.Filler = value); }

        internal Row(Table table, int rowIndex, int columns, int height)
        {
            _table = table;
            _rowIndex = rowIndex;
            Columns = columns;
            Height = height;
        }

        public Cell this[int column] 
        {
            get => _table[_rowIndex, column];
            set => _table[_rowIndex, column] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private int fHeight;
    public int Height 
    {
        get => fHeight; 
        set => fHeight = Math.Max(0, value);
    }
```

Comment: А... Ну да... На самом деле до изменений так и было. мне показалось, что set в таких случаях должен возвращать значение. Первый день на шарпах ^^. 
`public int Height 
        {
            get => Height; 
            set => Height = Math.Max(0, value);
        }`
и
`public int Height 
        {
            get => Height; 
            set => Math.Max(0, value);
        }`
дают одинаковый результат.

Comment: @VAVUS7 Использование свойства в сетере/гетере этого свойства ведет к бесконечной рекурсии.

Comment: @VAVUS7 Внимательно посмотрите на код в ответе. Это не то, как было "до изменений".

Comment: я думал об этом... Я думал, что наличие get внутри set игнорируется. И наоборот.